# Confusing Structure of Plugins and Platforms Folder

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using Ionic framework to start on a Cordova hybrid mobile application.

Installing Ionoic via NPM was successful and had no issues.

I am running the below command in a directory as shown below.

```
C:\wamp\www\my_cordova\> ionic start myapp
```

This creates a new folder called myapp inside my_cordova folder, which is fine.

But it also creates the plugins folder in C:\wamp\www\ folder. This is the case always how much deeper I create the folder structure. Even if I start a project in C:\wamp\www\my_cordova\level1\, still the plugins folder is created in C:\wamp\www\ folder.

The same happens for platforms folder too when I add them. They are created in C:\wamp\www\ folder.

Is this expected or is it something wrong from my side? I expect all the folders(plugins and platforms) to be created within the same folder directory where I start the ionic project.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the CLI. As the path has "www" in it, these issues happened.

When I tried the CLI commands in another path which does now have www in it, all went fine.